# in a Rails after_save callback, would the commit have finished and the change be accessible for a Sidekiq job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I have a Sidekiq job that is started in an after_save and it appears as if it is getting the wrong data and I'm curious if this is the behavior I should be expecting. This job's goal is basically to build a cached version of the object.

I have an item which can have is_enabled set to true / false.

In an after_save, I have:

```
after_save
   ItemWorker.peform_async
end
```

and in my worker, I have:

```
  def perform item_id
    mi=Item.find(item_id)
    Queryable.manage_object mi # <-- will build our cached objects here
  end
```

At the start of my after_save, should all my changes be already in the database and committed - is there any way Postgres could be locking the row at this point (I'm on Postgres 9.4)?

Is there a way for me to check whether it has been save or should I move this to an after_commit (or some other place)?

Answer (score 2):

There is a good chance that Sidekiq will run the worker before the new/changed data is committed to the database, which means the worker will see the wrong data.

As explained in the [Sidekiq FAQ](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/FAQ#why-am-i-seeing-a-lot-of-cant-find-modelname-with-id12345-errors-with-sidekiq), the best practice is to use `after_commit`:

> Sidekiq is trying to execute your job before the transaction has actually committed. Use Rails's `after_commit :on => :create` hook or move the job creation outside of the transaction block.

Comment: thx for posting to that - that makes sense (kinda) and I think it's what's going on here but seems a bit counter-intuitive. My understanding would be that an after_save would be after your primary object has been saved and an after_commit would be after ancillary objects have been saved (say you're forcing a transaction in your code). I mean it IS called after_save.

Comment: It is a little confusing, but that is indeed how ActiveRecord works: during `after_save` the changes have been "saved" but are not yet committed to the database. In a single threaded request/response scenario that distinction doesn't matter, but since Sidekiq is running in a separate process, the exact transaction boundary is very important.

Comment: hmm.... but if I select out a new copy of the same item at the end of my after_save, it does give me the correct value. I trust you're right that it has something to do with this transaction boundary but want to know more. Is there any place you can point me to? It seems like in both cases (the single process model and the background prcoess model), we are going to the database and selecting out the record. Does the sidekiq job some see it as an open transaction and then have accesss to the previous data where the single request / resposne sees the transaction as committed?

Comment: IE there is two copies of the data in effectively different states.

Comment: I think you need to revisit your understanding of database transactions. Sorry, I don't have a good reference handy, but the idea of transaction isolation is that, **yes, essentially the database is in two different states**. Querying the database within the uncommitted transaction gives you a different result than querying the same database from outside that transaction. That's how transactions work.